# Multiple Submits

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, submit

This is my code. `Onclick` of submit, if the answer is correct the value will be saved in database. What I want here is that, when I click on a submit button all other submit buttons in the form must be disabled. Can i do this? Please help me.

```
    <textarea name="questn" id="questn" readonly="readonly" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $quest['questnId']; ?>.&nbsp<?php echo $quest['question'];?></textarea>
   <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option" value="<?php echo $quest['optiona'];?>"/>
   <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option"  value="<?php echo $quest['optionb'];?>" />
   <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option"  value="<?php echo $quest['optionc'];?>" />
   <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option"  value="<?php echo $quest['optiond'];?>" />
```

The reason I used submit instead of radio is that i want the value on the button to be displayed over it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write an `onsubmit`  event on your form to disable all buttons.

```
<form action="xyz.html" onsubmit="handleSubmit()">
  <input type="submit" name="option" value="b1"/>
  <input type="submit" name="option" value="b2"/>
  <input type="submit" name="option" value="b3"/>
  <input type="submit" name="option"  value="b4"/>
</form>



function handleSubmit(){
   var list = document.getElementsByName('option');

   for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
      list[i].disabled=true;
   }

   alert('all disabled');
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4BDaU/1/

---

2) if you dont want to disable the one clicked, i will suggest use `onclick` on buttons to call the `handleSubmit`. the code will look like this.

```
  <input type="submit" name="option" onclick="handleSubmit(this)" value="b1"/>
  <input type="submit" name="option" onclick="handleSubmit(this)" value="b2"/>
  <input type="submit" name="option" onclick="handleSubmit(this)" value="b3"/>
  <input type="submit" name="option" onclick="handleSubmit(this)" value="b4"/>
```

you handle function will now accept `this` which will be than excluded in the loop.

```
function handleSubmit(current){
   var list = document.getElementsByName('option');

   for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
      if(list[i]!=current)   // new condition added
         list[i].disabled=true;
   }

   alert('all disabled');
}​
```

Also note that, you don't need add `onsubmit` in your `form` in this case

Comment: You may need to NOT disable the one clicked

Comment: I dont want to disable the one clicked. Can i do this?

Comment: i dont know why but its not working. Do i have to change anything. I dont know javascript.

Comment: @Avinash see this fiddle link.. it will help you understand better - http://jsfiddle.net/4BDaU/2/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
function disableEverything() {
    var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), l = inp.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) inp[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Then you can call this function `onClick` of any submit button.

---

Why can't you use radio buttons? Like this:

```
<label><input type="radio" class="mybutton" name="option" value="<?=$quest['optiona']?>" /> <?=$quest['optiona']?></label>
...
```

Comment: I want options such that value will be displayed over it. I dont think using radio i may be able to do it

Comment: I dont want to disable the one clicked. Can i do this?

Comment: Hey how to sumbit using javascript. If i could do that i may be able to get the value on submit.